# Possible Bug in pandas.groupby.agg?

Tags: python, pandas

I might have found a bug in pandas.groupby.agg. Try the following code. It looks like what is passed to the aggregate function fn() is a data frame including the key. In my understanding, the agg function is applied to each column separately and only one column is passed. Since the 'year' column appears in groupby, it should be removed from the grouped results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'year' : [2011,2011,2012,2012,2013], '5-1' : [1.2, 2.1,2.1,11., 13.]})

def fn(x):
    print x
    #return np.mean(x) will explode
    return 0


res = df.groupby('year').agg(fn)
print res
```

The above gives the output, which clearly tells me that x of fn(x) is passed as a DataFrame with two columns (year, 5-1).

```
   5-1  year
0  1.2  2011
1  2.1  2011
    5-1  year
2   2.1  2012
3  11.0  2012
   5-1  year
4   13  2013
      5-1
year     
2011    0
2012    0
2013    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, if you absolutely want the function applied to a `Series`, use the `{column: aggfunc}` syntax in `.agg()`.

That said, your code seems to work fine (at least on the current master). The function isn't actually being applied to the `year` column.

---

A bit of explanation.  For this I'm assuming that you are on an older version of pandas, and that that version had a bug that has since been patched. To reproduce the behavior *I think* you were getting, lets redefine `fn`:

```
In [32]: def fn(x):
    print("Printing x+1 : {}".format(x + 1))
    print("Printing x: {}".format(x))
    return 0
```

And let's redefine `df['year']`

```
In [33]: df['year'] = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

All these objects are defined in `pandas/core/groupby.py`.
The `df.groupby('year')` part returns a `DataFrameGroupby` object, since `df` is a `DataFrame`. `.agg()` isn't actually defined on `DataFrameGroupBy`, that's on its parent class `NDFrameGroupBy`.

Since this ins't a Cython function, things get handed off to `NDFrameGroupBy._aggregate_generic()`. That tries to execute the function, and if it fails, falls back to a separate section of code:

```
    try:
        for name, data in self:
            result[name] = self._try_cast(func(data, *args, **kwargs),
                                          data)
    except Exception:
        return self._aggregate_item_by_item(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

If the `try` part succeeds, the function is applied to the entire object (which is why `print x` shows both columns), and the results are presented nicely with the grouper on the index and the values in the columns.

If the `try` part fails, things are handed off to `_aggregate_item_by_item`, **which excludes the grouping column**.

This means that by changing your code from `return np.mean(x)` to `return 0`, *you actually changed the path the code follows*. Before, when you tried to take the `mean`, I think it failed and fell back to `_aggregate_item_by_item` (That's why I had you redefine `df['year']`, and `fn`, that will fail for sure). But when you switched to `return 0`, that succeeded, and so followed the `try` part.

This is all just a bit of guesswork, but I think that's what's happening.

I'm actually working on the group by code right now, and this issue has come up (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5264#issuecomment-30571813)). I don't think the function should ever be applied to the grouping column, but it *sometimes* is (R does the same). Post there if you have an opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

If `year` weren't included in the aggregation, how would you know what group you were aggregating over?

Comment: I mean year should not be passed to fn(x). You can write df.groupby('year').agg(np.mean) and it works. It definitely is because it only passes the '5-1' column to np.mean because np.mean(df) will raise an exception. But if you def fn(x): return np.mean(x) and then df.groupby('year').agg(fn) it stops working because a df of two columns are passed to np.mean.

Comment: Correct, numpy "ufunc"s are treated specially in pandas.

Comment: So how would you write a custom aggregate function? All examples I saw seems to expect a Series. Do you have any examples or references?

Comment: Actually your example with `def fn(x): return np.mean(x)` seems to work fine for me. In any case in general you can select a single column from a groupby, so in this case something as simple as `df.groupby('year')['5-1'].agg(fn)` would always work.

Comment: That won't work either. In my example the key column 'year' was passed to fn() which is the problem. After you gorupby the key column is supposed to be gone.